# Estimation of analytic function with monic polynomials

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f$ be a function analytic in $|z|<1+\varepsilon$ for $\varepsilon>0$. Then for every monic polynomial $p$, $$|f(0)|\leq \dfrac{1}{2\pi} \int_{0}^{2\pi} |f(e^{it})p(e^{it})|dt.$$

I was trying to get this inequality using Cauchy's integral formula but failed to do it. Moreover, I don't know how use the condition that it is monic polynomial.

So I would be very grateful if anyone can show in details how to prove it.

Answer (score 2):

Let $N$ the degree of the monic polynomial and $f(z)=a_0+\sum_{n\ge 1}{a_nz^n}, p(z)=z^N+\sum_{0\le k \le N-1}b_kz^k$,

hence $\bar{p(e^{it})}=e^{-iNt}+\sum_{0\le k \le N-1}\bar{b_k}e^{-ikt}$,

hence  $e^{iNt}\bar{p(e^{it})}=1+\sum_{1\le m \le N}\bar{b_{N-m}}e^{imt}$,

hence $f(0)=a_0=\dfrac{1}{2\pi} \int_{0}^{2\pi} e^{iNt}f(e^{it})\bar{p(e^{it})}dt$

Now take absolute values, use the usual integral inequality and you are done since $|p|=|\bar{p}|, |e^{iNt}|=1$

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But let me ask you the following question: How did you get that $f(0)=a_0=\dfrac{1}{2\pi}\int \limits_{0}^{2\pi}e^{iNt}f(e^{it})\overline{p(e^{it})}dt$? Could you give more details, please?

Comment: $e^{iNt}\bar{p(e^{it})}=1+\sum_{1\le m \le N}\bar{b_{N-m}}e^{imt}$ has all terms but $1$, positive powers of $e^{it}$ so when you multiply with an analytic function (which is also $a_0$ plus positive powers) all the terms except the $1$ times $a_0$ is a positive power which integrates to zero on the full circle - by continuity you can switch sums and circle integrals without any problem